# Get dynamically added element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace the text within a div which is getting dynamically added to a dialog element on clicking a link.

```
    var feedBackDialog;
    if(!feedbackDialog){
        $(".feedback_link").click(function() {
            //set contents of the dialog 'feedback-dialog' 
            $.get("/users/feedback", null, function(result) {

                feedBackDialog = $("#feedback-dialog").html(result). //set html content during callback
                    attr('title', title).
                    dialog({ autoOpen: true, width: 560, modal: true 
            });
        });
        }
    else
    {
        feedbackDialog.dialog({ autoOpen: true, width: 560, modal: true });
    }
    //change the text in the newly created element.
    $('#feedback-label').text($(this).attr('feedback_desc'));
```

An element with the id `feedback-label` exists in the html that I'm fetching. However, the last line's `$('#feedback-label')` does not work as the DOM has not been refreshed.

I tried doing `$("#feedback-dialog").find('#feedback-label')` but that does not seem to work consistently. Does anyone know of a good way of obtaining this newly created element? 
I know I can simply replace the string of the html `<div id="feedback_label"></div>` with the contents, but I'm looking of a nicer way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the last line to the callback function of `$.get`, because the contents will only be ready when the Ajax call has finished:

```
$.get("/users/feedback", null, function(result) {
       $("#feedback-dialog").html(result). //get HTML
                                attr('title', title).
                                dialog({ autoOpen: true, width: 560, modal: true });
       $('#feedback-label').text($(this).attr('feedback_desc')); //change the text in the newly created element.

});
```

Comment: The idea seems to be correct but the text does not add to the div on the first click.

Comment: No error message. I believe the problem lies within the fact that jquery's dialog does not include the text, since it's created *before* the change to the div.

Comment: I made the following change and got it to work(I turned off *autoOpen* and reopened the dialog after changing the label):      `feedbackDialog = feedbackDialog.dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 560, modal: true });$('#feedback-label').text($(this).attr('feedback_desc'));
                        feedbackDialog.dialog('open');`

Answer (score 3):

It's not because the dom hasn't been refreshed, it's because you're making an AJAX request that hasn't finished. Add the line of code to the success callback and you should be golden:

```
$.get("/users/feedback", null, function(result) {
  $("#feedback-dialog").html(result).attr('title', title).dialog({ autoOpen: true, width: 560, modal: true });
  $('#feedback-label').text($(this).attr('feedback_desc'));
});
```

Comment: +1. But the problem with this is that the dialog doesn't seem to contain the value the first time.